# Clicking a link in IE6 doesn't load page (internal DNS entry on our intranet)

Tags: dns, firewall, internet-explorer-6

I have a very strange problem that is only affecting some versions of IE6. The problem *does* affect IE 6.0.2900.5512, but does *not* seem to affect 6.0.3790.3959

Basically I work for a company and we have an intranet. While I'm not an expert on "internal DNS pointers", what I was able to do was create a website (let's say about football), and when an employee who is sitting behind the company firewall types the word "football" in to the web address bar of their web browser, they get redirected to a particular server. I am told this is some kind "internally pointing DNS entry".

So, I've set one of these up, and I have a placed a link to it on our company intranet page. However, when the link is clicked in IE6.0.2900.5512, the page goes blank. Clicking "refresh" then loads the correct page (the one specified in the link).

Can anyone help me out here. I have tried changing the way URL is formed, everything from //football to http://football/ etc.

The link works fine in every other browser and IE7+, but unfoturnatly, IE6 is still the most common browser in use at my organisation.

Comment: Why IE6, Why Why Whyyyyyyyy. What's your organisations address? I'm coming with the Human Rights comittee

Answer (score 2):

Solved. For some reason, having the charset set to utf-8 on the page being linked to was causing the freeze. Changing it to ISO-whatever fixed it. I'm not sure if the DNS thing had anything to do with it. Cheers.